# How to run a Game/Software with a proxy?

Tags: internet, proxy

How to run a software or a game using a proxy, I know how to apply a proxy on browser but how to do it for a PC software?

Note: Using a laptop running Windows Vista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game should have some configuration options where you can set the proxy.

If it doesn't(!) you can try to sockisfy the game. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS